# TexMaker (Ubuntu 12.04) Cannot open a style file

Tags: bibtex, texmaker

I am trying to compile a document in TexMaker with the following document class

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,showpacs,twocolumn]{revtex4-1}
```

I am using bibtex to display my bibliography. I have created a file 'ferroelectrics.bib' and use the following command at the end of my document

```
\bibliography{ferroelectrics}
```

When I try to compile this document using latex -> bibtex, the process exits with errors and the following error is reported in the .blg file that is generated:

```
I couldn't open style file apsrev4-1.bst
```

What's weird about this error is that when I compile using only the command line, I get no such error and the document compiles just fine. I have been doing various google searches all day trying to figure this out, but to no avail. What can I do to enable TexMaker to open apsrev4-1.bst?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you install the `texlive-full` package (or at least `texlive-publishers`)?

Comment: I had installed texlive 2012 from tug.org, since the `texlive-full` package is 3 years old. I just installed the `texlive-full` package to be on the safe side, and now TexMaker works fine. Why should this be the case?

Comment: It sounds like TexMaker is using the packages from the Debian repositories rather than the TL from TUG (does it include apsrev4-1.bst?).  I think you need to make sure your editor is pointed towards the distribution you want to use.  (I've never used TeXMaker, though, so I can't help with that; but there are lots of posts that talk about having a parallel installation.)